# Would turbulence from flowing streams into a system be a form of work or heat loss?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, flow, turbulence

[image]

Imagine a situation like this. If we consider the T-elbow to be our system, both the hot and cold streams are bringing energy into it (KE, flow energy, $u$).

However, in the middle where the streams are "clashing" there's going to some some turbulence and losses as a result. Would this be some form of work being done on the system? Heat loss?

Some of the molecules in one stream will be clashing and moving molecules from the other stream some distance, which is what made me think of work. But at the same time, this doesn't quite make sense to me because eventually this is probably being converted into thermal energy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The work on the macroscopic system (modeled as a control volume) occurs at the inlet boundaries of the hot and cold streams and at the outlet boundary of the shower head.  The turbulence at the T-elbow you refer to affects the pressures at the inlet boundaries, and this effects the work at the boundaries.  (These work quantities are usually included in the enthalpy term of the open system version of the 1st law of thermodynamics.)

In the microscopic differential version of the equation of motion (Newton's 2nd law), the turbulence effect is embodied in the turbulent stress tensor, and the local deformational work is included explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the terms "heat" and "work" in thermodynamics have a subtler meaning than in common language. *Work* is manifested by forces acting at the boundaries of the system, for example, a system expands/contracts against the pressure of the surroundings, or the boundaries of the system move in such a way that weights are raised or lowered, or springs get compressed/expanded and so on. *Heat* is energy transferred between two systems as a result of temperature difference. Finally, internal energy is storable energy that stays with the system until its state changes.

With this in mind, turbulence is a mechanism that converts part of the kinetic energy of a fluid to internal energy. This is the clashing of molecules you are describing, but this energy is not converted into macroscopic work, it causes molecules to move faster, and this would be manifested by a (small) increase in temperature. If this warmer fluid is placed into thermal contact with a colder fluid, then this extra energy could be extracted as heat.